# How to create a custom honeypot for WP Forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, spam-prevention, honeypot, wpforms

I use WP Forms on WordPress, and I'm looking to add a custom honeypot as an extra layer of protection against an influx of spam.

In an attempt to achieve this in a simple and effective, I've created a name field in the form which is hidden `display: none;` - So in theory this should mean, If this field gets filled in, then it's most likely always going to be spam.

I believe I had this working, but it's come to my attention the form is no longer submitting regardless of the hidden name field true or false.

I'm unsure if it's due to a recent update with WP Forms plugin or an issue with the function I was using.

Does anybody know how to achieve this or advise any issues with this?

Thanks

```
function forms_custom_honeypot( $honeypot, $fields, $entry, $form_data ) {
    $honeypot_class = 'fancy-name-field';

    $honey_field = false;

    foreach( $form_data['fields'] as $form_field ) {
        if( false !== strpos( $form_field['css'], $honeypot_class ) ) {
            $honey_field = absint( $form_field['id'] );
        }
    }

    if( !empty( $entry['fields'][$honey_field] ) ) {
        $honeypot = 'Custom honeypot';
    }

    return $honeypot;

}
add_filter( 'wpforms_process_honeypot', 'forms_custom_honeypot', 10, 4 );
```

Credit to @billerickson for forms_custom_honeypot.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be custom? I've used Project Honeypot for years.

Comment: Hi Jerry, not really, just as long as it works specifically with WP Forms, in the same manner described.

Comment: Looking more, I'm not sure it does (It has been a while since I looked!). Sorry to take up your time. However, after you figure this out, I recommend supplementing your honey pot with the Bad Behavior plugin, which will stop a lot of institutional spammers before they even load your page.

Comment: Have you tried anything they've recommended? https://wpforms.com/how-to-build-spam-free-wordpress-contact-forms-the-ultimate-guide/

Comment: Hi disinformation. Yes pretty much but custom honeypot worked best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to provide a quick update that I managed to solve the issue with the custom honeypot code working now with WPForms.

Answer is that the custom honeypot was setup as a First Last with Name on WPForms then it doens’t work. However, once changed back to simple text field it works fine and logs fine.

So, if you're following the work above, then Bill's recommendation is to always use the "Text" field and to avoid false positives give it a label that is not name or email because some users will let the browser pre-fill those in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just here to report I've used Bill's script successfully on sites for a long time, but it seems to not work with new sites I'm making with a Full Site Editing theme. I think it's a FSE thing rather than a WP 6 thing because old sites running 6+ are working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Bill got back to me today actually and said the custom honeypot is working fine for him and could only recommend enable WPForms Logging, which I've tried. Your comment is interesting because the site in question has Divi. So I'm wondering perhaps it is something to do then more with an update they have done regarding FSE.